# Disable inheriting the "Allow all users" rule from IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-deployment

I created a new site in IIS 7. This site is inheriting a rule to allow all users. I want to remove this rule but it won't let me. Is there a way to set the site to not inherit any rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for this is to use URL Authorization. See [here](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authorization) to install it. Then in IIS Authorization Rules you can remove the rule that allows all users to access the site.

[image]

Based on this previous question [IIS7 Authorization Rules / Config - Prompting Perpetually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389140/iis7-authorization-rules-config-prompting-perpetually)

Comment: May not work: I installed URL authorization but that did not enable me to remove the "Allow" rule for "All Users".

Comment: This solution is not applicable to all cases at all

Comment: A minor refinement, at least for Windows 7:  After installing URL Authorization you need to close out of IIS Manager and re-launch.  Then if you're grouping by Category, you can see the new "Authorization Rules" feature under the Security section.  From here, @Tim, you can remove the "Allow" rule for "All Users".

Answer (score 7):

Change your web.config f.e. in the following way:

```
<system.web>
   <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Anonymous users are identified with the questionmark.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx

You can do the same in IIS, what actually changes your web.config in the above way.

[image]

**Edit**: If this does not work try this at the top of the `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="Administrators" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authorization

**Edit2**: My last attempt ...

Change the permission on your application directory to not include inheritable permissions from it's parent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That still lets me in. I'm in an enterprise environment using Active Directory for authentication. I think everybody in the company is authenticated. Is there any way to give access to only one group of users?

Comment: It gives an error saying that remove is not recognized. I found out that writing `<deny users="*" />` at the end of the section fixes it. It has to be at the end though. It does not work otherwise. Bug??

Comment: It turned out I was using the wrong section. We should use URL Authentication for this, instead of .Net Autnentication

Comment: I know this is old, but it is important to note that Authentication is NOT Authorization. Authentication is the method by which you prove you are who you say you are, i.e. user verification. Authorization on the other hand is the set of permissions given to a particular user/role/group, etc. Authorization can only take place AFTER Authentication. :)